# How do you use Custom ID primary key in ASP.Net Zero framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an existing database from an old system and I want to retain the schema especially the primary key in each table. I notice that when I use ASP.Net Zero it uses a generic primary key "ID" but the schema I'm working on has a primary key "GroupID". I'm not sure how to apply this. Please help.

```
`[Table("GroupHeader")]
 public class GroupHeader : Entity<int> , IMayHaveTenant
 {
    [Column("GroupID")]
    public override int Id { get; set; }
    public int? TenantId { get; set; }
    public virtual string GroupTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual string GroupShort { get; set; }
 }`
```

Comment: I believe you will need to change the model post-generation, and update the PK field to point to your designated primary key.  Can you post the model in question that is problematic?

Comment: I added a snippet of my object. I already modified it. I added the lines "[Column("GroupID")]
        public override int Id { get; set; }"